# Bucket by fields present in returned documents using Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Our indexed documents do not have a completely fixed schema, that is, not every field is in every document.  Is there a way to create buckets based on the fields present in a set of documents (i.e. in response to a query) with the count of how many documents contain those fields?  For example, these documents that I just made up comprise the results of a query:

```js
{"name":"Bob","field1":"value","field2":"value2","field3":"value3"}
{"name":"Sue","field2":"value4","field3":"value5"}
{"name":"Ali","field1":"value6","field2":"value7"}
{"name":"Joe","field3":"value8"}
```

This is the information (not format) I want to extract:

```
  name: 4
field1: 2
field2: 3
field3: 3
```

Is there a way I can aggregate and count to get those results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, I think you can do it like this:

```
GET /some_index/some_type/_search?search_type=count
{
  "aggs": {
    "name_bucket": {
      "filter" : { "exists" : { "field" : "name" } }
    },
    "field1_bucket": {
      "filter" : { "exists" : { "field" : "field1" } }
    },
    "field2_bucket": {
      "filter" : { "exists" : { "field" : "field2" } }
    },
    "field3_bucket": {
      "filter" : { "exists" : { "field" : "field3" } }
    }
  }
}
```

And you get something like this:

```
   "aggregations": {
      "field3_bucket": {
         "doc_count": 3
      },
      "field1_bucket": {
         "doc_count": 2
      },
      "field2_bucket": {
         "doc_count": 3
      },
      "name_bucket": {
         "doc_count": 4
      }
   }
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a go.  I was looking at scripting as a means of dynamically discovering the field names but this is more straightforward.  Our schema isn't random so we know the set of possible fields even though every document will not have every field.